# A proof of a version of the Herschel-Maxwell theorem

Tags: probability

I am looking for the proof of the following statement, which I believe to be a version of the [Herschel-Maxwell theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell%27s_theorem). It would be nice if anyone could provide the proof, or point me to an online source where the proof is presented. The statement goes as follows:

Suppose $X_1$, $X_2$ are independent and $\exists \theta \neq \frac{N\pi}{2}$ such that $X_1\cos\theta + X_2\sin\theta$ and $-X_1\sin\theta + X_2\cos\theta$ are independent. Then $X_1$ and $X_2$ are Gaussian random variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neat theorem! This is much stronger (and I think more interesting) than the original Maxwell’s Theorem.

A proof can be found in Feller’s An Introduction to Probability Theory and Its Applications Vol 2, Chapter 3 Section 4.

https://www.climet.com/toolbox/feller-correction-calculator/Feller-1968.pdf